# JPA: Comparing (>=) ordinal enum in query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have an enumeration with int values assigned to each item.

```
    public enum RankEnum {
            NO_RANK(0),
            FIRST_RANK(1),
            ...,
            LAST_RANK(7);

            private int rank;

            RankEnum(int rank) { this.rank = rank; }

            public int getRank() { return this.rank; }
    }
```

The intetion of the integer values was to make it easier to compare different elements with each other, regarding their rank (for example e1.rank < e2.rank2). So i mapped them in my entity like this:

```
    @Column(...)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private RankEnum rank;
```

Unfortunately when I try to create a query to find for example all entities with a higher rank than another entity x the result is not correct.

```
    Select entity FROM Entity entity WHERE entity.rank > :rank
```

:rank is bound to x.getRank();

So the question would be: what is jpa actually comparing in this case? Since the mapping is ordinal I thought this should work, regarding that the values are stored as integers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well have you looked at what SQL is being generated?

Comment: ...where entity0_.RANK > ?

Comment: Okay, and what does RANK look like in the database? You say that the result "is not correct" - what happens, compared with what you'd expect?

Comment: In the database rank is a NUMBER(2,0) and seems to be correctly stored. In my test I've entity1.rank = NO_RANK (stored as 0) and entity2.rank = SECOND_RANK (stored as 2). When I execute the above mentioned query for entity1 I get an empty list, but I would expect entity2 as result.

Answer (score 1):

The ordinal of your enum has nothing to do with the rank you assign to each instance of the enum. Every enum has an ordinal. The ordinal starts at 0 for the first declared one, then 1, then 2, etc:

```
public enum Season {
    WINTER, // ordinal = 0
    SPRING, // ordinal = 1
    SUMMER, // ordinal = 2
    AUTUMN; // ordinal = 3
}
```

And enums are automatically comparable by their ordinal. So `Season.WINTER.compareTo(Season.SPRING) < 0`.

Comment: Ok, so forget about the integers I assigned... But still the query I posted in my question doesn't work. So comparing enums based on their ordinal value doesn't seem to work with JPA.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging, and see which SQL query is generated, and with which arguments. Tell us what the database contains, whet the test does, what you expect as result and what you get instead. Check your test: the title ofyour question says `>=`, but the query says `>`.